# Why are modules not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am very new to angular and I am trying to understand what is happening here. I have two different modules. 'defaultValueSelect'is used to select from the option menu of fruits and the other one is to select date from the calendar. These two work fine separately (when I say separately, I mean I completely remove the html and script of one and let the other be ). When I run them together only one of them works. Please help

```
<body>
    <script>
    angular.module('defaultValueSelect', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        availableOptions: [
          { id: '1', name: 'Option A' },
          { id: '2', name: 'Option B' },
          { id: '3', name: 'Option C' }
        ],
        selectedOption: { id: '3', name: 'Option C' } //This sets the default value of the select in the ui
    };
}]);
    angular
.module('firstApplication', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
.controller('dateController', dateController);

    function dateController($scope) {
        $scope.myDate = new Date();
        $scope.minDate = new Date(
           $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
           $scope.myDate.getMonth(),
           $scope.myDate.getDate());
        $scope.maxDate = new Date(
           $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
           $scope.myDate.getMonth() + 2,
           $scope.myDate.getDate());


    }
    </script>
    <div ng-app="defaultValueSelect" ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <form name="myForm">
            <label for="mySelect">Make a choice:</label>
            <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
                    ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id"
                    ng-model="data.selectedOption"></select>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <tt>option = {{data.selectedOption}}</tt><br />
    </div>
    <h1>sdfdsaf</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">


        </div>
        <div ng-app="firstApplication">
            <div class="datepickerdemo" ng-controller="dateController as ctrl" ng-cloak>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h4>&nbsp;&nbsp;Select  Date</h4>

                    <md-datepicker ng-model="ctrl.myDate"
                                   md-placeholder="enter date"
                                   md-min-date="minDate"
                                   md-max-date="maxDate">
                    </md-datepicker>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there should be one main module in your app and you could inject other modules into the main module:

```
angular.module('defaultValueSelect', ['firstApplication'])
```

then in HTML in ng-app declare only main module

```
<div ng-app="defaultValueSelect">.....</div>
```

further you could declare ng-controller for different block of codes.

Hope it would help!!

Comment: yea rest of the code remains same and your both modules will work!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two separate module in your code.
Your module may look like

```
   angular.module('defaultValueSelect', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']).contoller('myCtrl',$scope){

// 
}
```

.

Import other module in your main module